# BOINC: Run several tasks in each time, ubuntu/debian

Tags: boinc

I've setted a BOINC on my Ubuntu 12.04 Server, but it runs only 1 task at the same time.
How to set limit of tasks, running in each time?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think it is the right place to ask but what the hell. You can set number of available CPUs using ncpus option inside cc_config.xml file (On Ubuntu it should be somewhere in /etc/boinc-client/ dir). You can read more about settings here: http://boinc.berkeley.edu/wiki/Client_configuration. Per project settings are usually available on projects sites. You can also connect to the boinc-client using from remote host using boinc-manager. But seriously you should move this question to http://superuser.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by zero323, each tasks runs in one CPU. The default available CPU number is 1, so you will have to change this in BOINC preferences.

Go to  `BOINC manager > Tools > Computing preferences > Processor usage`

Find **On multiprocessor systems, use at most** and replace the value to your desirable percentage of processors (If you want them all, use 100%. If you have a quad-core machine, you will have 4 tasks running at a time)

I also recommend you to take a look at **Use at most** option, since each CPU will have this percentage of usage. Keep an eye on your CPUs core temperature using the command `sensors`